# segmentation fault created by fortran if tests

Tags: debugging, if-statement, segmentation-fault, fortran

Suppose I have the following code

```
    IF (a.eq.0.or.M(a)) THEN
```

With a an integer and M(1:3) an array of logicals.
If a is equal to 0, then I expect the first test to catch it and the second one never to be evaluated. However, if I use the intel fortran compiler and compiles with

```
    -check all
```

then I got a segmentation fault. No error occurs without this debugging option.
Is it a standard behavior? For many languages it is said explicitly in the manual that for

```
    IF (A.or.B) THEN
```

if A is true then B is not evaluated. Does the Fortran standard explicitly requires that A and B can be evaluated even if does not impact the final result?

Comment: Getting a segmentation fault from an out-of-bounds subscript when the compiler option for subscript checking was used -- I'd call that a bug in the implementation of subscript checking.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Fortran allows for, *but does not guarantee*, short-circuit evaluation of logical operators](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/ch1-8.html#12). So to be safe, you will have to write your code under the assumption that each operand is evaluated.

Comment: +1, the language specification does not guarantee short circuiting. Compaq/DEC supported it, Intel does not, and I can't speak to the other compilers.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Thanks for the verification!

Comment: @user7116 This has been denied by Steve Lionel, for instance in [this thread](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/282534). Neither DVF, CVF nor IVF ever guaranteed evaluation in left-to-right order, so short-circuit evaluation, even if implemented by the optimizer, is not usable in this context.

Comment: @user7116 Interestingly, the documentation has not changed much since VAX Fortran: [VAX](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/vax/lang/fortran/AA-D034E-TE_VAX_FORTRAN_Language_Reference_Manual_Jun88.pdf) p.94, [CVF](http://jp.xlsoft.com/documents/intel/cvf/cvf_lref.pdf) p.102 and [IVF](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/190_U4_FORTRAN_DGR_1.pdf) p.809