# Store all r combinations of a list

Tags: recursion, fortran

I need a general program in fortran to obtain all possible combinations of `r` elements in a list of `n` elements. I have found this code that prints all the combinations (r=3, n =5) but I need them to be stored in an array.

I tried to record them as rows near the `write` statement but it does not work. Turning the recursive subprogram into a recursive function is also not working.

```
program combinations
  implicit none
  
  integer, parameter :: m_max = 3
  integer, parameter :: n_max = 5
  integer, dimension (m_max) :: comb
  character (*), parameter :: fmt = '(i0' // repeat (', 1x, i0', m_max - 1) // ')'
  
  call gen (1)
contains
  recursive subroutine gen (m)
    implicit none
    
    integer, intent (in) :: m
    integer :: n
    
    if (m > m_max) then
      write (*, fmt) comb
    else
      do n = 1, n_max
        if ((m == 1) .or. (n > comb (m - 1))) then
          comb (m) = n
          call gen (m + 1)
        end if
      end do
    end if     
  end subroutine gen
end program combinations
```

Comment: It would very much help us if you explain what you mean by "it does not work" and "also not working". What, precisely, did you try? How precisely, did it fail to work? At compile time? At run time? Or wrong answers? Or something else?

Comment: What I firstly tried was to define an array A with the dimensions of the resulting list and fill each row, with the array 'comb'. So after the statement write it would read as 
 
cont = cont +1

A(cont,:) = comb

where cont is define at zero above.

Comment: Refering to previous comment I forgot to mention that the compilation succed but I can not acces to A

Comment: Can you [edit] your code to include what you're doing with your `A` array. It's hard to work out what you're doing or why it's going wrong from the comments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, mixing global variables and recursive procedures is a good way to cause a lot of unnecessary confusion and debugging, so let's turn `comb` and `n_max` into procedure arguments, use `size(comb)` to give `m_max`, and for now replace `fmt` with `*`:

```
program combinations
  implicit none

  integer :: comb(3)

  call gen(comb, 1, 5)
contains
  recursive subroutine gen(comb, m, n_max)
    integer, intent(inout) :: comb(:)
    integer, intent(in) :: m
    integer, intent(in) :: n_max

    integer :: n

    if (m > size(comb)) then
      write (*, *) comb
    else
      do n = 1, n_max
        if ((m == 1) .or. (n > comb(m - 1))) then
          comb(m) = n
          call gen(comb, m+1, n_max)
        end if
      end do
    end if
  end subroutine gen
end program combinations
```

The next thing to note is there's a subtle bug in your code. The line

```
if ((m == 1) .or. (n > comb (m - 1))) then
```

isn't guaranteed to work if `m=1`. Fortran [does not guarantee short-circuiting of logical operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609449/segmentation-fault-created-by-fortran-if-tests), so even if `(m == 1)` evaluates to `.true.`, the `(n > comb (m - 1))` could be evaluated, causing a segfault. Let's get around this by introducing a variable `n_min`, and calculating it correctly:

```
  recursive subroutine gen(comb, m, n_max)
    integer, intent(inout) :: comb(:)
    integer, intent(in) :: m
    integer, intent(in) :: n_max

    integer :: n
    integer :: n_min

    if (m > size(comb)) then
      write (*, *) comb
    else
      if (m == 1) then
        n_min = 1
      else
        n_min = comb(m-1) + 1
      endif

      do n = n_min, n_max
        comb(m) = n
        call gen (comb, m+1, n_max)
      end do
    end if
  end subroutine gen
```

Okay, now we can start thinking about returning the combinations from `gen`. To do this, let's change `gen` from a `subroutine` into a `function`, and have it return a 2-D array. We're going to need to append one 2-D array onto another, so let's write a function to do that now:

```
  function append_combinations(input, new_combinations) result(output)
    integer, intent(in) :: input(:,:)
    integer, intent(in) :: new_combinations(:,:)
    integer, allocatable :: output(:,:)

    allocate(output(size(input,1), size(input,2)+size(new_combinations,2)))
    output(:, :size(input,2)) = input
    output(:, size(input,2)+1:) = new_combinations
  end function
```

and now the whole program looks like

```
program combinations
  implicit none

  integer :: comb(3)
  integer, allocatable :: combs(:,:)
  integer :: i

  combs = gen(comb, 1, 5)

  write(*, *) ""
  do i=1,size(combs,2)
    write(*, *) combs(:,i)
  enddo
contains
  recursive function gen(comb, m, n_max) result(combs)
    integer, intent(inout) :: comb(:)
    integer, intent(in) :: m
    integer, intent(in) :: n_max
    integer, allocatable :: combs(:,:)

    integer :: n
    integer :: n_min
    integer, allocatable :: new_combs(:,:)

    if (m > size(comb)) then
      write (*, *) comb
      combs = reshape(comb, [size(comb),1])
    else
      if (m == 1) then
        n_min = 1
      else
        n_min = comb(m-1) + 1
      endif

      allocate(combs(size(comb), 0))
      do n = n_min, n_max
        comb(m) = n
        new_combs = gen(comb, m+1, n_max)
        combs = append_combinations(combs, new_combs)
      end do
    end if
  end function gen

  function append_combinations(input, new_combinations) result(output)
    integer, intent(in) :: input(:,:)
    integer, intent(in) :: new_combinations(:,:)
    integer, allocatable :: output(:,:)

    allocate(output(size(input,1), size(input,2)+size(new_combinations,2)))
    output(:, :size(input,2)) = input
    output(:, size(input,2)+1:) = new_combinations
  end function
end program combinations
```